# notepad++ find certain lines, alter them (to lower case)

Tags: regex, notepad++

Trying to get the following done with regex:

In the lines that begin with 0: I'm looking to change the words from BLA_BLA to Bla Bla (Remove underscore, and convert to lowercase, keeping the first letter of each word uppercase).

Original:

```
ACACIA_STAIRS:
  0: ACACIA_STAIRS
ACACIA_TRAPDOOR:
  0: ACACIA_TRAPDOOR
ACACIA_WOOD:
  0: ACACIA_WOOD
ACTIVATOR_RAIL:
  0: ACTIVATOR_RAIL
AIR:
  0: AIR
ALLIUM:
  0: ALLIUM
ANDESITE:
  0: ANDESITE
```

Post find/replace:

```
ACACIA_STAIRS:
  0: Acacia Stairs
ACACIA_TRAPDOOR:
  0: Acacia Trapdoor
ACACIA_WOOD:
  0: Acacia Wood
ACTIVATOR_RAIL:
  0: Activator Rail
AIR:
  0: Air
ALLIUM:
  0: Allium
ANDESITE:
  0: Andesite
```

Any help would be really appreciated!
Here is the full file I'm trying to convert: https://pastebin.com/raw/mKFcn9FM

Comment: Hi, please tell us exactly what you are trying to achieve. Currently, you are making us play "spot the difference".

Comment: 0: 'ACACIA_BOAT'
to
0: 'Acacia Boat'

Basically remove underscore in the lines with 0: and then change to lower case (leaving first letter of each word as uppercase)

Comment: Hm, close, that one changes it to: ACACIA_STAIRS:
  0: 'A  0: 'acaciastairs' - so its adding an A which I can remove, but then it's not replacing the _ with a space.

Comment: Then try `(?:^\h*0:\h+'.|\G(?!^))([a-zA-Z]+)(_+)?` and replace with `(?1\L$1)(?2 )`

Comment: That one is not converting anything at all. 0 occurrences. (my settings are wrap around, regular expression.) Also the actual file has 1,740 lines and not all names start with A

Comment: Here is the full file:
https://pastebin.com/raw/mKFcn9FM

Comment: Did you try again? I edited that comment seconds later.

Comment: Still showing me 0 occurences. Using it on the linked pastie.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/WDKmPp9.png

Comment: In your question all those strings are enclosed in single quotes, right? In the provided content in pastebin they aren't. Try `(?:^\h*0:\h+'?.\K|\G(?!^))([a-zA-Z]+)(_+)?` with the same replacement string.

Comment: `(?:\G(?!^)_|^\h*0:\h*')\K([^\W_])([^\W_]*)` => `\U$1\L$2` works for me.

Comment: Thanks guys :). Using @revo strings I have got it down to this: https://pastebin.com/raw/3CNF67CZ - all that's missing is every word to begin with an uppercase letter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notepad++ (due to its support of boost syntax) supports conditional statements in replacement string so we have no problem in converting those letters into their lowercase form as well as replacing underscores with a space character simultaneously.

```
(?>^\h*0:\W+\K|\G(?!^))(.)([a-zA-Z]+)(_+)?
```

and replace with

```
\U$1\L$2(?3 )
```

Regex break down:

```
(?> # Start of non-capturing group (atomic)
    ^\h*0:\W+\K # Match beginning of line following a sequence of spaces
                 # following `0:`  and some non-word characters
                 # then forget all (\K)
    | # Or
    \G(?!^) # Continue from previous match
) # End of non-capturing group
(.) # Capture first letter
([a-zA-Z]*) # Capture the rest of letters
(_+)? # Capture underscores, optionally
```

Comment: This almost got it for me! :D - https://pastebin.com/raw/0wyLhvdd - Only thing is the first two letter of the first word are uppercase, as opposed to the first letter only.

Comment: @Chr901 I updated the answer. There was a redundant dot which I removed. You may want to accept this answer as the correct answer by clicking the check mark at the left.